# Connect to a c# websocket server with socket.io.(How to do it?)

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket, socket.io, .net-core

To put it simply I am looking for a way to connect to a c# websocket server using socket.io on the client side.

Okay, so I tried to create a simple websocket server in c# using a [httpListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.7.2) and a simple webpage with a script that used plain websockets and it worked out well, but then I realized that my client isn't really run on a browser and websockets don't work out well out of the context of a browser.

So I did up some digging and found out that I could use socket.io to solve my problem, but then socket.io uses some special websockets that use some sort of unique protocol. My Websocket server catches the request sent from socket.io but I have no way to comunicate with it. As far as I understand I have to perform a specific handshake to comunicate through the websocket provided by the socket.io.
Here is the code so far:

```
    private static readonly HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();
    private static readonly Mutex signal = new Mutex();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:9000/");
        httpListener.Start();
        while (signal.WaitOne())
        {
            ReceiveConnection();
        }
    }

    public static async Task ReceiveConnection()
    {
        var context = await
            httpListener.GetContextAsync();
        if (context.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            var webSocketContext = await context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null);
            var webSocket = webSocketContext.WebSocket;

            var recvArr = new byte[1024];

            while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(recvArr), CancellationToken.None);

                var str = Encoding.Default.GetString(recvArr);
                Console.WriteLine(str);

                await webSocket.SendAsync(
                    new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Message from server ")),
                    WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }

        signal.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
//client
function connectToServer()
{
    console.log('Function started');

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000',{upgrade: false, transports: ['websocket']});

    socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log(socket.connected); // true
    });
    //socket.send("Some Data")
    socket.emit('foo',"hello");
}
```

This simple websocket server that I've found will actually recive something from socket.io sometimes an empty string or sometimes some sort of wierd request, but I cannot send or receive any useful data through the socket.

Please be a bit more forgiving as this is the very first question I asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: Start by using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check to see that you are actually sending a message.  Also make sure you are reaching the send code by putting a break point on the send code.

Comment: I can assure you that the request arrives but it needs to make a handshake and I do not know how to make it.

Comment: The handshaking is the HTTP headers in the request.

Comment: Hmm, I see... it will take me a bit to get a hold of how to use wireshark but here is what I've discovered in the meantime.

Comment: My request headers are :GET ws://localhost:9000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: file://
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Sec-WebSocket-Key: SHnnjQjf5sFpz1FsI+QfXA==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits

Comment: My response headers are: HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 3zHKmW+tuM62oBTZWkzuXxEX0mo=
Date: Tue, 19 Feb 2019 09:11:47 GMT

Comment: And I have updated the client script to send emit send

Comment: and now this warning pops up in the browser : WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

Comment: Only empty strings pop up in the server which is to be expected.

Comment: My best guess is that they start establishing the connection but they will not actually establish it, I will play around with wireshark in the meantime and tell you what I've found there.

Comment: Wireshark is telling a lot.  First you are using http1.1, http1.0 is stream mode where all the data is in one request. http1.1 is chunk mode and client must send next chink message to get mode data,otherwise, will get a time out.  A response ends with a 200 done.  Chunk mode returns a 100 and client must send next chunk message.  User default agent will vary depending on default IE of client.  You can override in client request to allow more than one type IE. Servers do not always work with every Browser.  You are using gzip (compressing) which means client must unzip data before using.

Comment: HPPT uses TCP for transport layer.  TCP max size is ~1500 bytes.  So each HTTP message can consist of one or more HTTP.  So you have to make sure the TCP doesn't close.  In the sniffer with the TCP you may see [FIN] which indicates the connection closing.  Sniffer will show the TCP and then the combined HTTP associated with the TCP datagrams.

Comment: You can modify client code and/or server code to use Stream Mode instead of Chunk Mode.

Comment: I am having the same problem today. Did you manage to solve?

Comment: @user3780549 saddly no, it is solvable, but you would have to do some header magic, maybe search for a nugget package that supports socket.io, this is the best advice that I can give.